# Each level is one scene?

Tags: 2d, unity

I'm planning to get into Unity 2D tools - so in order to start off I decided to create a little breakout clone. However, I'm not sure how to manage levels. When I wrote Breakout using MonoGame, I just had one class Level which read a XML-file for the level itself (kind of a simple tilemap).

Now that Unity has a graphical interface I could probably just create one scene for each level and put all the blocks in there. Is this a normal approach to handle levels in Unity - or would it be more appropriate to have one scene that also loads objects by using something like a XML file?

Thanks!

Comment: You can still do the same in one scene, you just need to manage how you clear the stages and create new layouts in it.

Comment: 1 scene = 1 level... Simple :)

Comment: @savlon for a game like breakout 1 scene per layout would be redundant. You can simply remove your objects and create a new layout by reading the xml file.

Comment: @Sidar On the other hand though, building one scene per level for a simple game like Breakout might be a good introduction to how unity works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you could do a new scene for each level, but I highly recommend the other approach of one scene that simply places objects based on data in an XML file. Separate scenes in Unity are intended for loading/unloading graphics and code when each level is significantly different, but if each level is pretty much the same objects just with the objects in different positions (like, say, a level in Breakout) then using separate scenes is rather inefficient.